# Obfuscation when InternalsVisibleTo attribute is used?

Tags: c#, obfuscation, internalsvisibleto

I want to use the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute solely to allow meaningful unit tests.

However, I am worried that when I will build for release the `internal` members will not get obfuscated, even though no friend assemblies will be part of the release build.

Is there anything I can/need to do that will cause these `internal` members to be considered truly `internal` for release builds? Cannot find a clear answer either way on this online.

FYI: I have not made a choice for a specific obfuscator yet. Any answers to this question may influence that choice.

Comment: What about using a directive to wrap the InternalsVisibleTo attribute?

Comment: @pickles, can you give an example? I don't quite understand how this would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a [pre-processer directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). You can either define your own symbol or use the built in RELEASE or DEBUG symbols

```
#if !RELEASE
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("X")]
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks @pickles, I got it! This seems like a very elegant solution. Marked as answer.

Comment: Seems like this should be a textbook case for unit testing of commercial code. Odd, that it isn't more common in unit testing discussions and documentation.

Comment: Unearthing an old thread, but could this be bad practice for security reasons, in any way?